# Tips for the "Beat Zico" trophy

Tags: achievements, wipeout-hd

In *Wipeout HD* (PS3), the "Beat Zico" trophy is one of the hardest trophies I have ever tried to obtain! I'm doing all of the barrel rolls from this video to get the time needed:

Even then I only come within 1 second of getting the par time, I can't find any way to cut my time down further than this. The barrel roll onto the walkway at the end is quite difficult, I end up swerving a lot.

Tips guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ps3trophies.org](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/wipeout-hd/guide/):

> I recommend setting up a speed lap
>   session with 99 laps in, this will
>   then give you 99 laps to try and beat
>   the required lap time.
>
> TURN PILOT ASSIST OFF!
>
> The best route for this trophy would
>   be:
>
> 1. Do 1 lap around and save your speed boost. As you get near to the
>      starting/finishing line you should use
>      it. This gives you a big boost and an
>      extra valuable second on the next lap.
> 2. As you go around the first corner try to hit all 3 speed pads,
>      the first is in the middle of the
>      track and the following two are on the
>      outside lane. After you have hit the
>      last one try to move your ship back to
>      the left hand side of the track.
> 3. Now there is a bum in the track. If you hit it right, tilt your ship
>      upwards & use your speed boost, you
>      should be able to fly into the air
>      giving you enough time to do your 1st
>      barrel roll.
> 4. As you land a barrel roll you get a speed boost. Hopefully you will
>      land at the top of a ramp going down
>      to another part of the track. You
>      should fly off of this giving you some
>      more air that will enable you to your
>      2nd barrel roll.
> 5. As you land try to hit the speed bump and fly close to the right hand
>      side of the track to turn the corner
>      nice and tight.
> 6. THIS IS NOW THE HARDEST PART TO PERFORM!! As you go around the left
>      try to hit two speed bumps in one go,
>      head to the left after the speed bumps
>      to the high ledge shortcut. Head to
>      the RIGHT of this ledge where it is
>      slightly higher, you are aiming to try
>      and get high enough to quickly perform
>      your 3rd barrel roll. You need to
>      quickly do the barrel roll because you
>      only have about 1 second air time, as
>      you come back down try to maneuver
>      yourself back into the middle of the
>      ledge.
> 7. Now try to keep on the ledge for a few seconds until you have to jump
>      off of the left hand side, here you
>      will have to perform your 4th barrel
>      roll. Try to land on the speed pads at
>      the bottom for a further speed boost.
>      Now just cross the finishing line and
>      hope that your time was under the
>      required target.
>
> This is another trophy that requires
>   you to have patience but with practice
>   you should get it over time.

Finally, this is the suggested video to follow for pinning down the precise barrel roll locations: